# docker COPY all fails when not in C drive

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

NOTE: I'm on windows 10, using docker-machine / virtual box

I have a project which builds and runs just fine when on my **C:\** drive.

If I copy all files to my second hard drive **F:\** the `COPY . /path` command in my Dockerfile appears to succeed, however when I inspect that directory in the container it's empty.

My docker file;

```
FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && a2enmod rewrite negotiation

COPY docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY docker/apache/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY . /srv/app

WORKDIR /srv/app
```

My docker-compose.yml file;

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/app
```

The odd thing here is that the first two `COPY` commands work

```
COPY docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY docker/apache/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

I can navigate to those two directories and see the two files individually with the right content. Some resources suggest the container does not have access to my second drive, but it clearly does, else these files would also not work.

FYI I'm using the following to build and then inspect the container

```
docker-machine up -d --build
docker-machine exec app bash
ls
```

**UPDATE**
If I change the copy folder to `/var/www/html` the command works properly. I'm currently only putting the files in `/srv/app` because I've been following tutorial. I'm not aware of the advantage/disadvantage of this at this stage.

---

**SOLUTION**
Thanks to @LinPy I used this comment to help me get the right setting: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3908#issuecomment-412385611

I opened a command prompt in C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox and ran the following command.

```
VBoxManage.exe sharedfolder add default --name "/f" --hostpath "f:\\" --automount
```

My VirtualBox settings now looks like this;

[image]

Comment: did you already configure drive `f` as shared in docker settings?

Comment: I'm using docker machine, so I'm not sure how I can do this. I have tried to add `F` as a shared folder in virtual box, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
docker-machine stop

vboxmanage sharedfolder add default --name "project_name" --hostpath "<full_project_path>" --automount

docker-machine start
```

then configure the `mount`

```
volumes:
  - /project_name:/path/in/container/project_name
```

when that did not help, try this:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-share-folder "\\?\f:\paht1\path2:installdir" test2
```

you can see also this [issue](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3908)

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I ended up running this `VBoxManage.exe sharedfolder add default --name "/f" --hostpath "f:\\" --automount` which did the job