# How to Access File Syetm of a Docker running on Linux Machine

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, docker-machine

I am working on a web application developed on .net core 2.0 and the same is hosted on a Linux machine (Fedora OS) using docker image.

The application has a document manager, which is storing and reading files from an external source(a network share / physical path on the base machine). This was working fine on normal dev environment and windows machines.

Please advice, how to get the file system / file path on Linux system with Docker.

```
var pathFolder = "E:\\DocLib\\";
var filePath = pathFolder + "\\" + newFileName;
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476559/docker-copy-all-fails-when-not-in-c-drive/57478050#57478050

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker COPY all fails when not in C drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476559/docker-copy-all-fails-when-not-in-c-drive)

Comment: when running in a docker container, your application basically doesnt have access to the 'host' machine's file system. It can only access the file system within the container. It is generally bad practice to include file paths like "E:\\..." because these are subject to change depending on the environment. Rather use `Shared Folders` when deploying your docker app, and configure the path through environment variables.